# XML Javascript undefined error in ie9

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have a 'jargon buster' on my site that uses an xml file to load an A-Z of words which when clicked display a brief short explanation of each word. This works fine in all browsers bar the latest ie's which i get an 'undefined' error with. The jscript im using is below

```
Jargon = {
    xmlfile:    'http://www.mysite.com/jargon.xml',
    xml:        null,
    wordHolder: 'words',
    defHolder:  'definition',
    idprefix:   'jargon_',
    selected:   null,
    init:       function () {
        var con = Jargon.xhcon();
        Jargon.wordHolder = $(Jargon.wordHolder);
        Jargon.defHolder = $(Jargon.defHolder);
        if (!con || !Jargon.wordHolder || !Jargon.defHolder) {
            return;
        }

        function conComplete(oXML) {
            Jargon.xml = oXML.responseXML;
            //Jargon.showWords('a');
        }
        con.connect(Jargon.xmlfile, 'GET', Math.random(), conComplete);
    },
    showWords:  function (c) {
        if (Jargon.selected) {
            Jargon.selected.className = '';
        }
        var words = Jargon.getWords(c);
        while (Jargon.wordHolder.childNodes.length > 0) {
            Jargon.wordHolder.removeChild(Jargon.wordHolder.childNodes[0]);
        }
        while (Jargon.defHolder.childNodes.length > 0) {
            Jargon.defHolder.removeChild(Jargon.defHolder.childNodes[0]);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            var o = document.createElement('a');
            o.href = 'javascript:Jargon.showDef(\'' + words[i].id + '\');';
            o.id = Jargon.idprefix + words[i].id;
            //o.onclick = Jargon.showDef;
            o.appendChild($t(words[i].name));
            Jargon.wordHolder.appendChild(o);
            Jargon.wordHolder.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
        }
        if (!words.length) {
            var o = document.createElement('p');
            var s = 'There are no words for the letter ' + c.toUpperCase();
            Jargon.wordHolder.appendChild(o.appendChild($t(s)));
        } 
    },

    showDef: function (id) {
        var o = $(Jargon.idprefix + id);

        if (Jargon.selected) {
            Jargon.selected.className = '';
        }

        if (o) {
            o.className = 'selected';
            Jargon.selected = o;
        }

        var defobjs = Jargon.getDef(id);

        while (Jargon.defHolder.childNodes.length > 0) {
            Jargon.defHolder.removeChild(Jargon.defHolder.childNodes[0]);
        }

        var heading = document.createElement('span');
        heading.className = "jargtitle";
        heading.appendChild(document.createTextNode(defobjs[1][0].textContent));

        Jargon.defHolder.appendChild(heading);

        var definition = document.createElement('span');
        definition.className = "jargdefinition";

        definition.appendChild(document.createTextNode(defobjs[0][0].textContent));

        Jargon.defHolder.appendChild(definition);
    },

    getWords: function(c) {
        var x = Jargon.xml;
        var letters = x.getElementsByTagName('letter');
        var oLetter = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
            if (letters[i].getAttribute('id') == c) {
                oLetter = letters[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!oLetter) {
            return [];
        }

        var words = [];
        for (i = 0; i < oLetter.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var oJargon = oLetter.childNodes[i];
            if (oJargon.nodeName == 'jargon') {
                var s = Jargon.getName(oJargon);
                words[words.length] = {
                    id: oLetter.childNodes[i].getAttribute('id'),
                    name: s
                };
            }
        }
        return words;
    },
    getDef:     function (id) {
        var x = Jargon.xml;
        var j = null;
        var temp = new Array(2);
        var jargons = x.getElementsByTagName('jargon');
        for (var i = 0; i < jargons.length; i++) {
            if (jargons[i].getAttribute('id') == id) {
                j = jargons[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!j) {
            return [];
        }

        //return [];

        for (i = 0; i < j.childNodes.length; i++) {
            if (j.childNodes[i].nodeName == 'name') {
                temp[1] = j.childNodes[i].childNodes;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < j.childNodes.length; i++) {
            if (j.childNodes[i].nodeName == 'desc') {
                temp[0] = j.childNodes[i].childNodes;
            }
        }
        //return [];
        return temp;
    },
    cloneNode:  function (oldNode, deep) {
        deep = (deep) ? true : false;
        // a replacement to the normal dom clone node
        // this will copy xml nodes to html nodes
        // which can then be inserted into the document
        // scope in all browsers
        // See for for the bug http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/12/xmlhttp_notes_c.html
        var newNode = null;
        if (oldNode.nodeType == '3') {
            // textnode
            newNode = $t(oldNode.nodeValue);
        }
        else if (oldNode.nodeType == '1') {
            // element node
            newNode = document.createElement(oldNode.nodeName);
            if (deep) {
                for (var i = 0; i < oldNode.childNodes.length; i++) {
                    newNode.appendChild(Jargon.cloneNode(oldNode.childNodes[i], true));
                }
            }
        }
        return newNode;
    },
    getName:    function (oJargon) {
        for (var i = 0; i < oJargon.childNodes.length; i++) {
            if (oJargon.childNodes[i].nodeName == 'name') {
                var oName = oJargon.childNodes[i];
                var s = '';
                for (var j = 0; j < oName.childNodes.length; j++) {
                    if (oName.childNodes[j].nodeType == 3) {
                        // text node
                        s += oName.childNodes[j].nodeValue;
                    }
                }
                return s;
            }
        }
        return '';
    },
    xhcon:      function () {
        var xmlhttp, bComplete = false;
        try { xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); }
        catch (e) { try { xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
        catch (e) { try { xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); }
        catch (e) { xmlhttp = false; }}}
        if (!xmlhttp) {
            return null;
        }
        this.connect = function(sURL, sMethod, sVars, fnDone) {
            if (!xmlhttp) {
                return false;
            }
            bComplete = false;
            sMethod = sMethod.toUpperCase();

            try {
                if (sMethod == "GET") {
                    xmlhttp.open(sMethod, sURL+"?"+sVars, true);
                    sVars = "";
                }
                else {
                    xmlhttp.open(sMethod, sURL, true);
                    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Method", "POST "+sURL+" HTTP/1.1");
                    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && !bComplete) {
                        bComplete = true;
                        fnDone(xmlhttp);
                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.send(sVars);
            }
            catch(z) { return false; }
            return true;
        };
        return this;
    }
}
```

In terms of how im calling the jscript im using `<li><a href="javascript:Jargon.showWords('f');">a</a></li>`

which loads a list of all items that begin with f then when i click one of items from that list say "Fiduciary" it triggers `javascript:Jargon.showDef('f1');` which in turns loads the  and  into a definition div

however in ie9 it displays "undefined" . It works in all other browers

Example of the XML below:

```
<letter id="f"> -<jargon id="f1"> <name>Fiduciary</name> <desc>in a position of trust. This includes people such as trustees looking after trust assets for the beneficiaries and company directors running a company for the shareholders' benefit.</desc> </jargon> -<jargon id="f2"> <name>Forfeiture</name> <desc>the loss of possession of a property because the tenancy conditions have not been met by the tenant.</desc> </jargon> -<jargon id="f3"> <name>Freehold</name> <desc>describing land that only the owner has any rights over.</desc> </jargon> -<jargon id="f4"> <name>Free of encumbrances</name> <desc>no one else having any rights over something. When property is owned by someone and nobody else has any rights over it, it is owned free of encumbrances.</desc> </jargon> </letter>
```

Comment: Hi, if you press the "F12" key in the IE9 browser it will bring up a development tools window. There you can examine the contents of any of the variables in your javascript, look at element properties etc., you can also set breakpoints in the code. Try using this to debug the code. Regards

Comment: Did you get this error IN `showWords` or while call the `showWords` itself?

Comment: No showWords works fine just showDef doesnt...